# Trying to get a sum using reduce method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the sum of all (a) properties and console.log says NAN

```
const numbers = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 6 }, { a: 3 }, { d: 4 }, { e: 5 }, { f: 5 }];

const filterNumbers = numbers.reduce((currenttotal, item) => {
  return item.a + currenttotal;
}, 0);
console.log(filterNumbers);
```

is there something wrong?
trying to get the sum of only a keys

Comment: `{ d: 4 }`, `{ e: 5 }`, and `{ f: 5 }` do not have a property `a`

Comment: `return (item.a||0)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate to be the person that takes someone's comment and makes an answer out of it, but as @dandavis has suggested, you need to, in someway, default to a value if the 'a' key doensn't exist.

This can be done in a variety of ways:

**[Short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#short-circuit_evaluation):**

```
const filterNumbers = numbers.reduce((currenttotal, item) => {
  return (item.a || 0) + currenttotal;
}, 0);
```

**[The `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):**

```
const filterNumbers = numbers.reduce((currenttotal, item) => {
  return ("a" in item ? item.a : 0) + currenttotal;
}, 0);
```

**[Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):**

```js
const filterNumbers = numbers.reduce((currenttotal, item) => {
  return (item.a ?? 0) + currenttotal;
}, 0);
```

**Checking for falsey values of item.a (basically longer short circuit evaluation):**

```js
const filterNumbers = numbers.reduce((currenttotal, item) => {
  return (item.a ? item.a : 0) + currenttotal;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all elements have an `a` key. If you want to dynamically get whichever key is present, this should work:

```js
 const numbers = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 6 }, { a: 3 }, { d: 4 }, { e: 5 }, { f: 5 }];

    const filterNumbers = numbers.reduce((currenttotal, item) => {
        let keys = Object.keys(item);
        return item[keys[0]] + currenttotal;
    }, 0);
    console.log(filterNumbers);
```

Comment: Not to be "that" person, but this would fail if the object is empty :D

Comment: and it sums all the properties i only want a

Answer (score 0):

Since not all fields have an `a` key the reduce does not find a value and return `NAN`.

The solution it`s the same as the previous answer, but i rather use immutability in variables since prevents future erros.

```
const numbers = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 6 }, { a: 3 }, { d: 4 }, { e: 5 }, { f: 5 }];

const filterNumbers = numbers.reduce((currenttotal, item) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(item);
    return item[keys[0]] + currenttotal;
}, 0);
console.log(filterNumbers);
```

and in the case u need to sum only with the specific key:

```
const filterNumbers = numbers.reduce((currenttotal, item) => {
   return (item.a ?? 0) + currenttotal;
}, 0);
console.log(filterNumbers);
```

Comment: yes but i need only with the sum of a keys